# Count rails controller timing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, timing

I have a rails controller which renders a json.

```
render json: {
  data: some_data
}
```

Is it possible to use chrome devtools in order to count the timing?
What do Views stands for on the server logs.

```
Completed 200 OK in 2811ms (Views: 2709.8ms)
```

Comment: The timing of what? The network tab in chrome will tell you the response time of your server which isn't really that helpful. More useful i looking at the logs or services like new relic.

Comment: The timing spent on the controller.

Comment: If you are talking about production environment you should use some service like NewRelic as mentioned above. If you are talking about development environment, take a look at rack-mini-profiler gem https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler